# Reading joystick values with Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame, joystick

I want to read the values of an Logitech Logitech Extreme 3D Pro with a Raspberry Pi. I'm using the [pygame library](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html)

The script:

```
import pygame
import sys
import time

pygame.joystick.init()

print pygame.joystick.get_count()

_joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
_joystick.init()
print _joystick.get_init()
print _joystick.get_id()
print _joystick.get_name()
print _joystick.get_numaxes()
print _joystick.get_numballs()
print _joystick.get_numbuttons()
print _joystick.get_numhats()
print _joystick.get_axis(0)
```

The ouput:

```
1
1
0
Logitech Logitech Extreme 3D Pro
4
0
12
SDL_JoystickNumHats value:1:
1
SDL_JoystickGetAxis value:0:
0.0
```

There are 4 axes and I turned all of them.

I can't find the problem. I already tried using other axes.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Have you tried looping over `get_axis`, or handling `JOYAXISMOTION` events instead of polling? It's possible that with your joystick, it always treats the initial position as 0, so calling `get_axis` immediately after `get_init` will always return 0.0.

Answer (score 3):

If the problem is that the value is always 0, then try to do [`pygame.event.pump()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) before reading the values. I've had a similar problem and this helped.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem.  You have to write pygame.event.get() in order to read information from the joystick.  Otherwise it never updates.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather wait (even more in a thread)
for example :

```
    axes = [ 0.0 ] * your_joystick.get_numaxes()
    buttons = [ False ] * your_joystick.get_numbuttons()

    while self.keep_alive:
        event = pygame.event.wait()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             self.keep_alive = False
        elif event.type == pygame.JOYAXISMOTION:
            e = event.dict
            axes[e['axis']] = e['value']
        elif event.type in [pygame.JOYBUTTONUP, pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN ]:
            e = event.dict
            buttons[e['button']] ^= True
```